# Как исправить рекурсивный метод?

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Есть задача:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось сделать расчет корня + корня + корня, то есть:
sqrt(98) + sqrt(95) + sqrt(92), а мне нужно корень из корня из корня, как на картинке.

Есть наработка:

```
using System;

namespace std
{
    class program
    {
        public static double Sqrts(double x)
        {
            double result, fResult, sum;

            if (x <= 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            else if (x >= 1)
            {
                result = Math.Sqrt(x);
                fResult = result + Sqrts(x - 3);
                return fResult;
            }
            else
            {
                return x;
            }
        }
        // 2 5 8 11 14

        public static void Main()
        {
            double myResult = Sqrts(14);
            Console.WriteLine(myResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить?

Comment: `public static double Sqrts(double x) => Math.Sqrt(x + (x > 3 ? Sqrts(x - 3) : 0));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 return  Math.Sqrt(x + Sqrts(x-3));
```